# Calculate SNR of drifting signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, noise

I have a signal that is both noisy and drifts. I want to calculate the noise of the signal, but I think for this drift should not be taken into account as "noise". using the *snr()* funciontion in matlab will give me a really high noise value, I think because it takes into account the drift, right?
How can I calculate it? is there any function available for this?

In this picture, for instance, the noise should be around 2% right? ((22.45-22.36)/2)/22.38. (although what I really want is the SNR value)

Thank you!

[image: Signal that has drift AND noise]

Filtered signal with low pass filter with a really low frequency:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried windowing? It helps to get rid of the drift.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by identifying the drift of the signal with a low pass filter. Just subtract the filtered signal from the original signal. This will lead to noise signal with low drift.

Filtering the signal might be the most difficult task, but by playing around with the filter parameters this will work

Comment: I tried doing that but the filtered signal doesn't look pretty (as in, it's not a nicely shaped line). I put the filtered signal in the answer.